# Build fails because of System.Text.Json generated code

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, system.text.json

I'm using the source generation from System.Text.Json (version 6.0.5).

My code looks like this.

```cs
[JsonSerializable(typeof(AuthenticationToken))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(AuthenticationData))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(ApplicationSettings))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Refit.ProblemDetails))]
// (...)
public partial class JsonContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
}

// (...)
private static JsonSerializerOptions GetDefaultOptions()
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    options.AddContext<JsonContext>();

    return options;
}
```

This code is in a NetStandard2.0 library. Apart from the project and package references, the csproj only contains the following properties.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This code works locally in both Release and Debug configuration and with both Visual Studio 2022 and 2019.

### Problem

When I build the same code in my CI pipeline, it yields the following errors.

```
##[error]C:\WIN1809-01\_work\11\s\src\app\ApplicationTemplate.Presentation\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator\JsonContext.g.cs(10,6): Error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute' attribute
##[error]C:\WIN1809-01\_work\11\s\src\app\ApplicationTemplate.Presentation\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator\JsonContext.Type.g.cs(11,100): Error CS0102: The type 'JsonContext' already contains a definition for '_Type'
##[error]C:\WIN1809-01\_work\11\s\src\app\ApplicationTemplate.Presentation\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator\JsonContext.Type.g.cs(12,98): Error CS0102: The type 'JsonContext' already contains a definition for 'Type'
##[error]C:\WIN1809-01\_work\11\s\src\app\ApplicationTemplate.Presentation\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator\JsonContext.String.g.cs(11,102): Error CS0102: The type 'JsonContext' already contains a definition for '_String'
##[error]C:\WIN1809-01\_work\11\s\src\app\ApplicationTemplate.Presentation\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator\JsonContext.String.g.cs(12,100): Error CS0102: The type 'JsonContext' already contains a definition for 'String'
```

These are just the first few lines. There are actually ~200 lines of similar errors, all originating from `JsonContext.xxx.g.cs` generated files.

**Is this a known problem? Am I just missing some config?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The assembly containing the `JsonContext` declaration needs to have a **direct** reference to System.Text.Json. It cannot be a transitive reference.

---

In my case, I have multiple assemblies representing the applications layers:

```
DAL -> Business -> Presentation
```

I move my code (the `JsonContext` declaration) from the Presentation  assembly (which *relies* on the DAL assembly for the System.Text.Json reference) to the DAL assembly (which *has* the System.Text.Json reference) and it works now.